# Finding if data communication is possible

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

N routers are provided on x-axis and want to communicate to each other. One router can send a message to another one if the distance between them is less or equal to K.

Given  P pairs of routers, which want to send messages.We need to tell with "Y" or "N" weather data transmission between that pair is possible or not.

Note : More than 1 router can be on the same point on the X-axis.

Constraints :

```
1 ≤ N, P ≤ 10^5
0 ≤ Ai, K ≤ 10^9
1 ≤ A, B ≤ N
```

So i want a pretty efficient algorithm for each query.

Let if we have 5 routers,K=3 and 2 queries as follow :

Position of  routers : = 0 3 8 5 12

Query 1 : 1 2

Here answer is "Y" as both are in range of each other

Query 2 : 1 3

Here answer is "Y" as both are in range of each other
For pair (1, 3) router 1 can send a message to router 2, router 2 can send it to router 4 and it can send it to router 3.

Comment: This might be better for math exchange. Not sure this is even remotely a programming problem. I say math exchange because its a graph theory problem, probably. It's a "computer science" problem, but I have a feeling this will be flagged as off topic.

Comment: @Tommy Why math exchange?Its related to better and efficient algorithm

Comment: Just precompute and store the range of each router. Or, do you have memory constraints?

Comment: @Tommy Is graph theory not under algorithms?

Comment: @JanDvorak No memory constraints.

Comment: @JanDvorak Precompute what?I didnt get you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. what do you know in advance? What do you want to optimise for

Comment: Edit: it appears there is also a "computer science" exchange now, probably for exactly these reasons: http://cs.stackexchange.com. Also there exists a cstheory page which might be even better! http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @JanDvorak I want to efficiently report output to these queries

Comment: @Tommy Its not theory question please

Comment: "Given P pairs of routers, which want to send messages. We need to tell with "Y" or "N" weather data transmission between that pair is possible or not...So i want a pretty efficient algorithm for each query.": this is certainly a theory problem. It is totally separate from implementation in any language. I bet you would get answers near immediately on cs or cstheory.

Comment: If I understand you correctly - just remember for each router the first and the last router it can communicate with.

Comment: @Tommy Hey..I need to code it in c++ using efficient algorithm

Comment: Ok... Hint: can you partition a set of routers so that routers in the same set can talk to each other, and routers in different sets can't?

Comment: Another hint: look up "union find". Another hint: an easy algorithm can precompute in quadratic time. A better algorithm sorts the routers by x, then spends a linear amount of extra time.

Comment: @JanDvorak Quadratic time will not work as N is large

Answer (score 0):

First map the router position/distance:

```
List<int> Routers=new List<int>();

Routers.Add(0);
//....
Routers.Add(12);
```

Create the pairings:

```
class Pairs
{
int[2] Pair;
}

List<Pair> Pairings=new List<Pair>();


Pairings.Add({Routers.IndexOf(0),Routers.IndexOf(1)});
Pairings.Add({Routers.IndexOf(0),Routers.IndexOf(2)});
```

Create the check method:

```
private bool CanCommunicate(intx i1,inti2)
{
    if (Math.Abs(i1-i2)<=K
    return true;
    else
    return false;
}
```

Implement the alg:

```
foreach (Pair p in  Pairings)
{
  if(CanCommunicate(p[0],p[1])
  return "Y";;
  else 
  return "N";
}
```

Code is in `C#`

Comment: Its not necessary that they need to direct communicate.So please do update your answer

Answer (score 0):

The routers are on the x axis, so two routers can talk directly if the difference between them is less than the bounds, and two can talk indirectly if there is no gap between routers on the path between them on the x axis so large that messages cannot get through.

So sort the routers in order of ascending position on the x axis and then consider them in order of ascending x and break them into runs of routers which contain no gaps that are too big. Number the runs and then two routers can communicate if and only if they are both in the same number run.

Comment: Please explain with some example am not getting your approach ,Its similar to approch being discussed by Patricia Shanahan in his answer.Please provide some pseudocode for it

Answer (score 0):

Given indirect communication, I would begin by finding the gaps, the places along the x-axis where there is too big a separation between two adjacent routers for them to communicate.

For each router, record the location of the next gap to the right. Treat the end of the line as a gap.

Two routers can communicate if, and only if, they share the same next gap.

============================================================================

```
Sort the list of routers in ascending x co-ordinate order

Initialize integer groupIndex to 0.

For each router in x co-ordinate order:
  Mark it with the current groupIndex
  If there is a next router and it is more than distance K away, increment groupIndex

Two routers can communicate if, and only if, they are marked with the same groupIndex.
```

Comment: @user3786422 Since you recognized the similarity to another, differently worded, answer, you do seem to understand the idea.

Comment: Please do provide a example to proof its accuracy

Comment: An example is at best proof of existence of one combination of inputs for which the algorithm works, not a proof of correctness of the algorithm. However, if you are interested in examples, why not run a few through the algorithm above yourself?

Comment: Actually it would explain your thought pretty well

Comment: See my edited post.Is this what you were trying to say?

Comment: Do reply soon.I think their are some cases to handle

Comment: As pointed out in a comment on your question, "Stack overflow is not a code-for-me service".